# How do you translate “is all” used at the end of a sentence?

Tags: expressions, traduction, nuance

How would you translate the explanatory “is all”?

“I’m just worried about you, is all.”

“Well, all I was trying to say is we still have some left, is all.”

It’s basically used to explain reasoning behind something or why you’re feeling a certain way.

How would you translate this nuance into French?

Answer (score 7):

There is a similar phrase in French: *c'est tout*.

> Je me fais du souci pour toi, c'est tout.
>
> Je voulais juste dire qu'il nous en reste, c'est tout.

Answer (score 2):

I think just "quoi" might work too, though perhaps not as tentative as "is all."

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of tentativity (tentativeness?  tentativedom??).  But 'quoi' would be more familiar than "c'est tout", more firmly oral usage

Comment: @GeorgeM Agreed, you are right. I meant "tentative" in the sense that "is all" alters the tone of a statement to make it less direct, more limited or qualified. I suppose "is all" could be taken at face value as a frank assessment, but I think of it more as conversational filler.

Comment: So are the equivalents in French :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few locutions that can be used to render this idea;

> c'est tout, (c'est) que ça, (c'est) rien d'autre
>   *"que ça" is informal*

- Elle disait ça pour plaisanter, pas plus.
- Vous leur avez expliqué ces difficultés pour être tranquille, c'est tout; nous sommes bien conscient de ce fait.
- Tu ne ne veux pas monter sur tes skis parce que tu as peur, que ça.
- S'ils n'y arrivent pas c'est qu'ils ne se sont pas assez entrainés, rien d'autre.

It seems that the correspondance is not perfect: possibly, in French, this is not most often said so much in a mechanical way, there would be more intent in the words, a more expressly formulated drive at providing a real explanation can be felt. For instance "c'est tout" is rather a translation of "that's all".

Other expressions, not as common, are also used;

> (c'est) pas autre chose, il n'y a pas d'autre raison, pas plus

- Ils ne se parlent pas parce qu'ils sont fâchés, (c'est) pas autre chose; il y a une semaine de ça ils étaient ensemble.

frequency of use: the following ngrams do not represent the frequency of use of the locutions as translations of "is all" but as occurring at the end; they are given so as to get an idea of the frequency of use of the form itself. [before a semicolon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+plus%3B%2Cc%27est+tout%3B%2Cque+%C3%A7a%3B%2Crien+d%27autre%3B%2Cpas+autre+chose%3B%2Cpas+d%27autre+raison%3B&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20plus%20%3B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20tout%20%3B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cque%20%C3%A7a%20%3B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crien%20d%27%20autre%20%3B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20autre%20chose%20%3B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20d%27%20autre%20raison%20%3B%3B%2Cc0),
[before a full stop](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+plus%3B%2Cc%27est+tout.%2Cque+%C3%A7a.%2Crien+d%27autre.%2Cpas+autre+chose.%2Cpas+d%27autre+raison.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20plus%20%3B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20tout%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cque%20%C3%A7a%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crien%20d%27%20autre%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20autre%20chose%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20d%27%20autre%20raison%20.%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: i never knew about this “que ça” at the end of a sentence. how common is that?

Comment: @jacoballens The ngrams give only an idea (there sentences such as "Ils n'ont pas fait autre chose que ça." and one can't tell; it is not possible to code a comma in ngrams. So, I can't tell how common it is; what I can say is that it is for the least nformal and does not sound good; it might even be calle informal by some. Any way, it can't be used much, I never heard it used much.

Comment: Peut-être que _sans plus_ est plus usuel que _pas plus_, je sais pas trop si c'est équivalent, à toi de voir. La même chose pour _c'est seulement que_ vs. _c'est pas autre chose_. Ça vaut la peine de présenter une [définition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/is_all) en question ou de la chercher, on aurait pu voir qu'en fait ça découle de _that's all_ ou peut-être même que ce n'est pas autre chose que ça mais énoncé différemment (mais je ne l'affirme pas), voire avec une ponctuation différente...

Comment: Si « c'est tout » et « rien d'autre » sont idiomatiques et que « pas plus » est compréhensible (on entend plus souvent « rien de plus »), « que ça » est franchement douteux. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu.

Comment: @Blackhole Je dois dire que je ne le conçois pas vraiment, comme il me semble me rappeler son utilisation,  dans les réplique qui visent à une justification de motivation personnelle, mais plutôt dans les phrases qui sont l'assertion d'une cause (par exemple): « Il ne va plus à l'école parce que ses parents veulent le voir travailler, que ça(, pas autre chose).». Cependant, je ne peux pas assurer que je me rappelle cet usage sans le moindre doute. Je n'ai pas de doute pour « c'est que ça. », néanmoins, forme que je trouve correcte et voisine.